# Commonly accepted term for ways to present book content?

Tags: fiction, technique, non-fiction

Without regard to genre, is there a commonly accepted term for the various ways that book content can be presented?

For instance, consider the following (an incomplete list):

- Dialogue
- Diaries
- Letters
- Case studies
- Examples
- Analogies
- Lists
- Tables
- Illustrations
- Foldouts
- Popups
- Scratch 'n' sniffs

As best I can tell, the terms "literary device" and "narrative device" are used to describe plot, theme, PoV, voice, and such and do not include the actual presentations. Of course I could use the word "presentations" as a collective term, or perhaps "exhibits", but is there already an accepted term in the book world?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe there isn't really a set term for what you're describing, simply because different types of "presentations"--as you call them--are mostly exceptions, and not the norm :)

You could try giving a short explanation, such as, "This book was written in the form of a collection of letters," to get your point across.

Hope this helps!